# Shapekeys Keyframe All

Tags: animation, shape-keys

I thought this would be simple and straight forward to do: I would like to be able to keyframe all for all available / selected Shapekeys, in a way that I can run the playback and Blender will simply automatically record and keyframe the shapekeys on every frame.

Comment: hello, it's a bit hard to understand, could you please explain with some screenshots?

Comment: Basically I need "Auto-Rec" for keyframing animation (Shapekeys), but I cannot seem to do so.